# Asymptotic order and growth rates of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, asymptotics, geometric-group-theory

I am following Drutu and Kapovich's Geometric Group Theory. Growth rates of functions are compared using the order given by $\asymp$ which is defined as:

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. For functions $f, g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, write $f \preceq g$ if there exist $a,b>0$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in X, x\geq x_0$, we have $bx\in X$ and $$f(x) \leq a g(bx)$$

Then $f \asymp g$ if and only if $f\preceq g$ and $g \preceq f$.

**Question**: If a function $f$ satisfies $x \preceq f \preceq x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 1$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then does that mean $f \asymp x^\beta$ for some $1\leq \beta \leq \alpha$?

If the answer is no, what if we are working with the growth function $f_G(n)$ of a finitely generated group $G$. In this case, does it have to be the case that $\beta$ is an integer?

Comment: What about $f(x) = x\log(x)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah of course, thank you! Do you have any thoughts on what happens when $f$ is the growth function of a f.g. group?

Comment: Did you find the Wikipedia article on Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth? See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth) I *think* it answers your question as "yes" for those functions which arise as growth rate functions of groups, but would need to read it properly to verify.

Comment: @user1729 yes, I think that gives me what I was looking for! Can you think of a more direct proof of this fact? Also, the wiki article defines polynomial growth as there being a polynomial upper bound for the growth function, and the order of growth is defined as the least degree of such an upper bounding polynomial. For a general function with fractional order polynomial growth, this "order of growth" doesn't coincide with the fractional order of the polynomial growth? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure...did you find the bit in the article about the theorem of Bass and Guivarc'h?

Comment: @user1729 Yes that's the part which answers my question. A f.g. polynomial growth group (this includes non-integral orders, correct?) is virtually nilpotent, which by the Bass-Guivarc'h formula has polynomial growth of integer order.